# IO error for saunter.ini while setting up py.Saunter

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

While setting up py.saunter on my system, I am getting an IO error for saunter.ini file.

Directory structure is exactly as shown in the example - https://github.com/Element-34/Py.Saunter-Examples

Below is the error message -

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/src/conf/saunter.ini'
ERROR: Module: Tests could not be imported
(file:/Users/.../PythonWorkspace/PySaunter/src/scripts/Tests.py)
```

I know there are lot of import related questions. Most of them suggest to add **init**.py if not already there. I have added **init**.py in every folder.

The code snippet which reads saunter.ini is as below -

```
def configure(self, config = "saunter.ini"):
    self.config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
    self.config.readfp(open(os.path.join("conf", config)))
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running the project from eclipse as a unit-test which is why it was throwing import errors. 
Py.Saunter is an opinionated framework and does not support eclipse or any other IDE at this point. 
It works fine when executed from the command line as illustrated in the site - http://element34.ca/products/saunter/pysaunter

Should ensure to execute from the home directory.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really enough here to diagnose the problem. But, in the examples directory there is actually two different projects (ebay and sauce) -- you have to be in one of them, not the top.

Also, Py.Saunter won't create saunter.ini for you. You need to create it (most easily by renaming saunter.ini.default).

Oh, and don't try and run it from checkout from Github -- it really does need to be from an egg. If there are bits missing from http://element34.ca/products/saunter/pysaunter which prevent you from getting started, let me know and I'll modify the page.

(Now if only I remembered by SO credentials...)

Comment: I'd created a saunter.ini file and placed it under conf folder...as mentioned in the example.

Comment: I was running the project from eclipse as a unit-test. Py.Saunter does not support eclipse and needs it to be run from command-line.